# A list of basic integrals

Tags: reference-request, integration, big-list

I am in need of a list of basic integrals for my upcoming ODE test,
I have searched on Math.SE for a post that might help but I didn't find such a post.

When I write 'basic' I don't necessarily mean immediate integrals (such as $e^x,\sin x$) but also 'useful' ones such as $\ln x$. If there is also some common techniques (useful substitutions like the trigonometric substitutions, how to integrate a rational function, etc.) this would be helpful too (since it has been over a year since I tooked my exam on Calc II and I forgot some of this material, this might also save some time during the exam).

I would appreciate any reference for this matter.

Comment: Should I add 'big-list' tag as well ?

Comment: I would really recommend you to take a (couple of) good book(s), read and do as many exercises you can! That is really the best cure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the following "cheat sheets" helpful when I was going through ODE.

[Paul's Online Math Notes: Cheat Sheets](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/cheat_table.aspx)

The integral ones come in a full sized and condensed form.

[Integrals Cheat Sheet](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Calculus_Cheat_Sheet_Integrals.pdf)